# How to start activity from non-activity class,if first activity is simple java class?

Tags: android

I want to start activity from 1st java class that extends BroadcastReceicer class.so i can`t extends activity class to start activity of another java class by using startactivity method in 1st class.
Give me proper guidance what should i do now?

Answer (score 1):

use context in the Onrecieve function of the broadcastreciever,

```
context.startActivity(...);
```